# Chrome driver and chrome browser version is matching but selenium tests are failing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, typescript

I am trying to resolve a compatibility issue between Chromedriver and Chrome browser, but none of the solutions I have tried have worked so far(mentioned below). I have latest chrome driver and chrome browser version installed but seems like it’s pointing to a different chromedriver which I’m not sure where to find. Location of my  chromedriver is  /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver. Please kindly help me understand what is wrong here? I have added all the details below. Thanks for your help!!Specifications:

ChromeDriver  version 113.0.5672.63

Chrome browser version 113.0.5672.126

**ERROR** webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to session not created: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 108
Current browser version is 113.0.5672.126 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

Solution tried

- Uninstalling and reinstalling chrome driver by using brew install --cask chromedriver
- Uninstalling and reinstalling chrome browser
- Removing chromedriver from this location /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver and manually adding it to folder usr/local/bin
- xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/chromedriver to remove restriction

Comment: The answers here (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/51364/after-updating-google-chrome-and-selenium-tests-are-not-running-with-chromedriv) may help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Above issue is resolved. I was using npm install to update chromedriver version but it didn't work. Found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439276/npm-install-chromedriver-is-not-working-properly. Thanks